# Installed python package with `pip3`, but when I call it I get "No module named X"

Tags: python-3.x

I installed a module like this:

```
> pip3.8 install mssql-cli
```

but when I run it I get:

```
> 3002 ~$ mssql-cli -S 192.168.7.50 -d test-db
/usr/bin/python: No module named mssqlcli
```

I think `mssql-cli` is defaulting to the system--default python (2.x).  How do I tell it to use `python3.8`?

Yes, I'm on a Mac.  Python 3.8 is installed via Homebrew.

**Answering questions from comments:**

> What does `pip3.8 --version` say?

```
3044 ~$ pip3.8 --version
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

> And check that `which python3.8` points to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/python?

Not exactly.  Is that bad?

```
3048 ~$ ll `which python3.8`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 grantb  admin  40 Jul 24 10:57 /usr/local/bin/python3.8@ -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8
```

Comment: `pip3.8` already gets it to use `python3.8`. What does `pip3.8 --version` say? Make sure it's in the `.../python3.8/lib/site-packages` directory, and that `which python3.8` points to the python executable for the same installation?

Comment: Updated question with answer for you.

Comment: And check that `which python3.8` points to `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/python`? Also check that `pip show mssql-cli` shows you information about the correct package.

Comment: Not exactly.  Updated question with answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that if you look at the actual `mssql-cli` file it runs it using the `python` command. This (on my Mac) defaults to the 2.7 python. There are three solutions:

1. Add a line in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` that says `alias python='python3.8'`. Note that this will override your python2.7 (which is obsolete anyway).
2. Edit the last line of the file that comes up with `which mssql-cli` to say `python3.8 -m mssqlcli.main "$@"`. This has the disadvantage that you aren't really supposed to edit this, and that you'd need to do it every time you update this package, but it does work.
3. Run each `mssql-cli` command with the equivalent `python3.8 -m mssqlcli.main`.

Comment: I guess you mean there are 3 solutions? :)  The third one worked for me, the fastest and least-disruptive for my current need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another brave soul caught up in the tangled web of installing Python on a Mac.

[image: There really is an XKCD for everything.]

Your problem is that homebrew installed a version of Python in `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8`. Pip3.8, on the other hand, thinks Python is at `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/python`, so it installs its packages in *that python's* `site-packages` directory.

If you already had python with pip installed when you installed it from the Homebrew bottle, it won't overwrite the links you already had. One solution is to reinstall pip through the *correct* python.

```
python3.8 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

This should force a reinstall of pip, and since `python3.8` points to Homebrew's Python, it should install `pip` and `pip3` as pointing to that python.