# Where is mssql_cli installed in the MacOS?

Tags: sql-server

So I did this in my M1,

```
pip3 install mssql-cli
```

The 2nd time it says:

> Requirement already satisfied: mssql-cli in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (0.3)

```
From ls -l ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/mssql_cli
-rw-r--r--  1 haha  staff    39 Aug  8 17:39 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 haha  staff  2395 Aug  8 17:39 mssql_cli.py
```

I'm trying to do `mssql-cli -S localhost -U haha`

> zsh: command not found: mssql-cli

Same thing for `mssql` cmd.

So how should I run it from command line please?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104393/installed-python-package-with-pip3-but-when-i-call-it-i-get-no-module-named

Comment: found https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-cli and it seems to be working

Comment: Did you try `find ./ -name mssql-cli` or `sudo find / -name mssql-cli`? Potentially it's modifying your `PATH` so you may need to start a new bash/zsh session or Terminal window for that to take effect.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning forgot to do that, will try next time if i have to reinstall again, thx !